# How to display Alfresco Documents on Activiti form by passing the nodeRef

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I have an Activiti process with a Start Event. How can I show the Alfresco Document on the Form on a the Start Event by entering the nodeRef?

In production it will not be manual entering the nodeRef though but by passing it using the Activiti REST API. I need to be able to show the Alfresco document using the 'Display value' field on a form (on the Start event or maybe on a User Task which flows from it)

Comment: Do you mean you want to show an Alfresco Share style document preview? Or something else? And are you using ADF?

Comment: I would like to get the same result when i upload a document manually on a form on a start event then on the next User Task (whoch flows from the Start Event) has a form with a ‘Display value’ where the form variable is used which is coming from the Start Event. In this way i can see a little thumbnail on the User Task’s form and have the option to download the document if i click on it. So the same way, would this possible if i pass a nodeRef in the Start event (not uploading file) which will be ‘interpreted’ as alfresco document on the following form? I use Activiti App (Kickstart App).

Answer (score 2):

In the Enterprise version, there is in fact a feature to link Documents uploaded in Activiti with Alfresco using the [share connector](http://docs.alfresco.com/process-services1.6/topics/shareGuide.html).

In the community version, you'll have to implement your custom logic to store documents in alfresco and retrieve documents. a neat way would be to use Alfresco's [Restv1 APIs](https://community.alfresco.com/community/ecm/blog/2016/10/11/v1-rest-api-part-1-introduction).

Using these APIs you should be able to create your custom code in Activiti to interact with your repository.

Comment: I have the enterprise version. I am able to upload and download alfresco files from Activiti using 'Publish to Alfresco task' for upload and using the 'Attach File' for download from Alfresco on any form in Activiti KickStart App. My question is that how can i link a nodeRef (what i pass in one of the process variable) to an Alfresco document in Activiti App.

Comment: so you need nodeRef as input from the user, instead of selecting the file from the repository?

Comment: the nodeRef would come from a third party app (my own application). When this app creates a document in Alfresco Share, it could send the nodeRef of the newly created document to the Activiti process (probably using Activiti REST API). But would it be possible to interpret this nodeRef as an Alfresco Document in the Activiti form? (the less coding the better, hopefully there is some hidden feature in the Activiti KickStart app somewhere)

Comment: no, you'll need coding to get file with nodeRef from alfresco, create your custom stencil

Comment: A note of the "share" connector. 2 years ago we were tld in no uncertain terms tat the share connector was no longer supported and should not be used. The new way to handle is using the Application Development Framework widgets.